# TransformListener not working in nodelet

Tags: nodelet, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am porting a node to a nodelet and having trouble with the TransformListener. In the node it works, but not in the nodelet.

Overview:

1. TransformListener is a member variable of the nodelet class
2. after receiving the first pointcloud the TransformListener is tested:

**if( !tfListener->waitForTransform(target_frame_id, cloud->header.frame_id, cloud->header.stamp, ros::Duration(10.0), ros::Duration(0.1), error) ) ...**

No exception is thrown, it does simply fail. If I try a **tfListener->lookupTransform** afterwards it will throw an exception: *Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/velodyne] to frame [/world]*
A call to **tfListener->getCacheLength()** return 10 seconds, a tfPrefix is not set, an **tfListener->getAllFrames()** also returns all frames correctly.

The things I tried so far:

1. making the tfListener a boost shared pointer initialized in *onInit()* with different NodeHandles an Cache lengths.
2. Inserting a sleep() for 5-10 seconds after creating the Listener and before testing the Listener
3. Making a loop with intermitting ros::spinOnce()-Calls for 5-10 seconds
4. Different Durations for timeout and polling intervall in the waitForTransform()

As stated above, a node with a TransformListener() running parallel to the nodelets has no problem looking up the transform an all calls of getCacheLength(), getAllFrames() give identical results to the nodelet-TransformListener.

Anyone any suggestions?

Regards,
Torsten Fiolka

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43844/transformlistener-not-working-in-nodelet/) by [torstenfiolka](https://answers.ros.org/users/3208/torstenfiolka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-14**:
Try setting the time stamp to 0 instead of using `cloud->header.stamp` to check if there is any transform between your source frame and target frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With ros::Time(0) it works.

---

Originally posted by [torstenfiolka](https://answers.ros.org/users/3208/torstenfiolka/) with karma: 16 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0